# Regular Expression within URL

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, url-routing

I've tried searching for the answer but it's a tough question to ask in the first place, here goes.

Consider the following URL(s):

- hotels-london-kensington-5star
- hotels-london-kensington-mayfair-5star
- hotels-london-5star

the following would be returned using the correct regular expression:

- london-kensington
- london-kensington-mayfair
- london

I'm trying to use regular expression to get the centre value(s) ONLY. I know the first and last words of the string in all cases i.e. 'hotels' (first) and '5star' (last).

UPDATE: I need to use regular expressions as the URL's are being routed through Codeigniters URI router. The centre part of the URI is dynamically built for search results.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't a magic wand that you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.

Comment: Codeigniter uses regular expressions to handle such routing and is the only possible answer in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Since you know the first and last words, you also know their lengths.

```
$out = substr($in,7,-6);
```

Or more generally:

```
$out = substr($in,strlen($begin),-strlen($end));
```

EDIT: If regex is *required*, just use `/(?<=hotels-).*(?=-5star)/`

Comment: Much better in that case than using regular expressions!

Comment: Added more info, it requires reg exp due to Codeigniter routing.

Answer (score 3):

For such simple cases you can use a [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)

```
$parts = explode('-', $string);
$wanted = array_slice($parts, 1, count($parts)-2);
```

Update: A regular expression. I still think it's easier to split the string into pieces manually.

```
~hotels-(.+)-5start~
```

Comment: Added more info, it requires reg exp due to Codeigniter routing.